# Create a 'flyover' map animation using ggmap and gganimate

Tags: r, ggmap, gganimate

I have a dataset of people arriving in a location, how long they stayed, and their home locations.  I want to create an animated chart which 'flies' them to their destination, and returns them to their original point once their trip is over.  But I'm not sure if this is possible with `gganimate` or not.  At the moment I only seem to be able to do a "start" and "end" frame, though it's a little hard to tell whether it just doesn't have enough frames to do the intended action.

Here's something like what I have so far:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(gganimate)

#Coordinates
europecoords <- c(left = -23, bottom = 36, right = 27.87, top = 70.7)
londonareacoords <- c(left = -.7, bottom = 51, right = 0.2, top = 52)
londonpointcoords <- as.data.frame(list(lon = -.14, lat = 51.49))

#Get the map we'll use as the background
europe <- get_stamenmap(europecoords, zoom = 4, maptype = "toner-lite")

#Sample dataset configuration
numberofpoints <- 10
balance <- 0.1

#Set up an example dataset
ids <- seq(1:numberofpoints)
arrivalday <- sample(x = 30, size = numberofpoints, replace = TRUE)
staylength <- sample(x = 7, size = numberofpoints, replace = TRUE)
startlocationlondonarealon <- sample(x = seq(londonareacoords['left'] * 10, londonareacoords['right'] * 10), size = numberofpoints * balance, replace = TRUE) / 10
startlocationlondonarealat <- sample(x = seq(londonareacoords['bottom'] * 10, londonareacoords['top'] * 10), size = numberofpoints * balance, replace = TRUE) / 10
startlocationeuropelon <- sample(x = seq(europecoords['left'] * 10, europecoords['right'] * 10), size = (numberofpoints * (1 - balance)), replace = TRUE) / 10
startlocationeuropelat <- sample(x = seq(europecoords['bottom'] * 10, europecoords['top'] * 10), size = (numberofpoints * (1 - balance)), replace = TRUE) / 10
startlocationlon <- c(startlocationlondonarealon, startlocationeuropelon)
startlocationlat <- c(startlocationlondonarealat, startlocationeuropelat)

points <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID = ids, arrivalday, staylength, departureday = arrivalday + staylength, startlocationlon, startlocationlat))

#Map the sample dataset to check it looks reasonable
ggmap(europe) +
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x = startlocationlon, y = startlocationlat), col = "blue", size = 2) +
  geom_point(data = londonpointcoords, aes(x = lon, y = lat), col = "red")


#Separate the events out to rearrange, then glue them back together
event1 <- points %>%
  mutate(Event = "Day Before Arrival", Date = arrivalday - 1) %>%
  mutate(Lon = startlocationlon, 
         Lat = startlocationlat) %>%
  select(ID, Event, Date, Lon, Lat)

event2 <- points %>% 
  mutate(Event = "Arrival Date", Date = arrivalday) %>%
  mutate(Lon = londonpointcoords$lon[1],
         Lat = londonpointcoords$lat[1]) %>%
  select(ID, Event, Date, Lon, Lat)

event3 <- points %>% 
  mutate(Event = "Departure Date", Date = departureday) %>%
  mutate(Lon = londonpointcoords$lon[1],
         Lat = londonpointcoords$lat[1]) %>%
  select(ID, Event, Date, Lon, Lat)

event4 <- points %>%
  mutate(Event = "Day After Departure", Date = departureday + 1) %>%
  mutate(Lon = startlocationlon, 
         Lat = startlocationlat) %>%
  select(ID, Event, Date, Lon, Lat)

events <- rbind(event1, event2, event3, event4) %>%
  mutate(Event = factor(Event, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("Day Before Arrival", "Arrival Date", "Departure Date", "Day After Departure"))) %>%
  mutate(ID = factor(ID))

#Make an animation
ggmap(europe) +
  geom_point(data = events, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, group = ID, col = ID), size = 2) +
  #geom_point(data = londonpointcoords, aes(x = lon, y = lat), col = "red") +
  transition_manual(Date) +
  labs(title = "Date: {frame}") +
  NULL
```

[image]

But as I said, the points don't seem to be 'flying' as much as just appearing and disappearing.  Should I be using a different data format?  Transition type?  Number of frames?  (I'm having trouble finding documentation on any of the above, which is part of why I'm stuck...)

Comment: From the help on `transition_manual()`: "This transition allows you to map a variable in your data to a specific frame in the animation. **No tweening of data will be made** and the number of frames in the animation will be decided by the number of levels in the frame variable."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Final result

[image: 7]

### Code

```
library(ggplot2)    
library(ggmap)
library(gganimate)
ggm <- ggmap(europe) +
    geom_point(data = events,
               aes(x = Lon, y = Lat,
                   colour = ID, group = ID, shape = Event),
               size = 3, alpha = 0.8) +
    transition_time(Date) + 
    labs(title = paste("Day", "{round(frame_time,0)}")) +
    shadow_wake(wake_length = 0.1)
animate(ggm, fps = 24, duration = 16)
```

========================================================

## Step-by-step

You have lots of moving parts there. Let's break it down a bit:

### 0. Load libraries

```
library(ggplot2)    
library(ggmap)
library(gganimate)
library(ggrepel) # will be useful for data exploration in step 1
```

### 1. Data exploration

```
ggplot(data = events, aes(x = ID, y = Date, colour = Event)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image: 1]

We see, that the arrival and departure events are each quite close together for each plane. Also, there is always a gap of a couple of days inbetween. That seems reasonable.

Let's check the `Date` variable:

```
> length(unique(events$Date))
[1] 24
> min(events$Date)
[1] 2
> max(events$Date)
[1] 33
```

Okay, this means two things:

1. Our data points are unevenly spaced.
2. We don't have data for all `Date`s.

Both things will make the animation part quite challenging.

```
ggplot(data = unique(events[, 4:5]), aes(x = Lon, y = Lat)) + 
    geom_point()
```

[image: 2]

Furthermore, we only have 11 unique locations (== airports). This will probaly lead to overlapping data. Let's plot it by day:

```
ggplot(data = unique(events[, 3:5]), aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, label = Date)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_text_repel()
```

[image: 3]

Yup, this will be fun... Lots of things happening at that airport in the middle.

### 2. Basic animation

```
gga <- ggplot(data = events, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat)) +
    geom_point() +
    transition_time(Date)
animate(gga)
```

[image: 4]

We used `transition_time()` and not `transition_states()`, because the former is used for linear time variables (e.g., second, day, year) and automatic interpolation, while the latter gives more manual control to the user.

### 3. Let's add colour

```
gga <- ggplot(data = events, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, colour = ID)) +
    geom_point() +
    transition_time(Date)
animate(gga)
```

[image: 5]

It's starting to look like something!

### 4. Add title, transparency, increase size

```
gga <- ggplot(data = events, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, col = ID)) +
    geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5) +
    transition_time(Date) + 
    labs(title = paste("Day", "{round(frame_time, 0)}"))
```

Note the rounded `{round(frame_time, 0)}`. Try using `{frame_time}` and see what happens!

[image: 6]

### 5. Add some pizzaz

```
gga <- ggplot(data = events, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, col = ID, group = ID, 
                                 shape = Event)) +
    geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5) +
    transition_time(Date) + 
    labs(title = paste("Day", "{round(frame_time, 0)}")) +
    shadow_wake(wake_length = 0.05)
animate(gga)
```

[image: 8]

Looks good, let's finish it up!

### 6. Add the map, make animation slower, tweak some details

```
ggm <- ggmap(europe) +
    geom_point(data = events,
               aes(x = Lon, y = Lat,
                   colour = ID, group = ID, shape = Event),
               size = 3, alpha = 0.8) +
    transition_time(Date) + 
    labs(title = paste("Day", "{round(frame_time,0)}")) +
    shadow_wake(wake_length = 0.1)
animate(ggm, fps = 24, duration = 16)
```

[image: 7]

Not too shabby, eh? As a side note: `animate(ggm, nframes = 384)` would have had the same effect on the animation as `fps = 24` with `duration = 16`.

> If you have any question please do not hesitate to shoot me a comment.
>   I will try my best to help or clarify things.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to explain each piece of the analysis.